# Handling command line argument in python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a django project which is running on python2, however there is one library which only runs on python3. So in order to execute a statement, I'm invoking python3 code by using os.popen (python3 code is in separate file).

python2 code

```
import os
url = "https://example.com/blklstleo/drake-sweeterman"
cmd_str = 'python3 v3.py ' + url
x = os.popen(cmd_str).read()
print x
```

another file with python3 code named "v3.py"

```
import os
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
x = os.popen('scdl -l '+ sys.argv[1])
```

This is throwing some error

```
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: Don't use os.popen, use subprocess

Comment: I have no idea about how to use subprocess and how to capture its output

Comment: `out = subprocess.check_output(["scdl", "-l", sys.argv[1]])`, what does scdl do?

Comment: it prints the some url which I want to capture in the python2 code
    x = os.popen(cmd_str).read()

Comment: Did you try the subprocess code?

Comment: I don't see `.read()` in `v3.py` after `x = os.popen()` -- is it your actual code that produces this error? Provide the full traceback.